# Glassfish V3 using up all available memory

Tags: memory, glassfish, java

I have a Virtual Server with 1GB of RAM. When i start glassfish with `asadmin start-domain` it instantly allocates all available memory, although i defined `-Xmx128m` in my domain.xml. Am I missing an option here? How can I prevent glassfish from using all free memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish minimum required RAM is 1GB. You can check this documentation right here: [GlassFish Enterprise Server v3 Hardware and Software Requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7688/abpaj/index.html). So define -Xmx to be less then 512M will not going to work.

**EDIT**: I just realize that you have ask this question 7 months ago. I hope my answer help you out

Comment: i'm still watchin this - thanks for your answer anyway

Answer (score -1):

I have some experiences. First of all check memory usage before running Glassfish. I started with Centos 5, after switching off some services it consumes about 256M RAM. When I start domain another 240M is consumed. When I log into admin console of Glassfish another 150m. I check the RAM with "free" command. Additionaly noticed that sequence start-domain, stop-domain causes some memore leak, since the ram used is grather than before runninig Glassfish. I have changing Xmx for admin server to 192M and it runs however consuming more that that limit.

Centos 5.9 86_64
Glassfish 3.1.2.2
JVM Oracle 1.7u21